# compilation of \setmathfont commands takes minutes with lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math

I have a code that shows how fonts look like. The code compiles in 10 seconds with only Latin Modern examples. But if I add the examples for math fonts for Termes, Pagella, XCharter and others it takes minutes to complete the compilation (I stopped 2:10 for this code).

Why does it take so long and how can I prevent it?
Working with lualatex and this code hardly usable due to the long compilation time.

The example is not minimal but should be enough to reproduce the problem.

```
% !TeX encoding=utf8
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\fontstring}{Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.}
\newcommand{\mathstring}{$f(u,v) = \iiint \left[u\nabla^{2}v+\left(\nabla  u,\nabla  v\right)\right]\mathrm{d}^{3}V$}

\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{gray!10}
\colorlet{tablesubheadcolor}{azure3!30}


{ % start a group 
    \small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
    % the table
    \begin{longtblr}[
        caption = {Font examples},
        label = {tab:doc:Font:Gallery}]
        {
            colspec = {X[1,l]>{\ttfamily}X[2,l]},
            width = 1.0\textwidth,
            row{odd} = {bg=tablerowcolor},
            row{1}   = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily\upshape},
            rowhead = 1,
            rowfoot = 0,
        }       
        \hline % Table Header
        Font & Example \\ 
        \hline %        
        %
        \SetCell[c=2]{l,bg=tablesubheadcolor} Latin Modern Family \\
        Latin Modern Roman   & \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} \rmfamily \fontstring \\
        Latin Modern Sans    & \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}  \sffamily\fontstring \\
        Latin Modern Mono    & \setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}  \ttfamily \fontstring \\
        %
        \SetCell[c=2]{l,bg=tablesubheadcolor} Math Fonts \\
        %
        Latin Modern Math       & \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}       \rmfamily \mathstring \\
%       TeX Gyre Termes Math    & \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}    \rmfamily \mathstring \\
%       TeX Gyre Pagella Math   & \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}   \rmfamily \mathstring \\
%       Charter - math version  & \setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}   \rmfamily \mathstring \\
%       Garamond math version   & \setmathfont{Garamond-Math}       \rmfamily \mathstring \\
%       Cambria Math            & \setmathfont{Cambria Math}        \rmfamily \mathstring \\
        %       %
        \hline
        %
    \end{longtblr}  
} % close the group
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use setmathfont inside a cell?

Comment: Off-topic: The `unicode-math` package loads the `fontspec` package automatically. No need to load the `fontspec` separately as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does it take so long and how can I prevent it?

Section 4.3, entitled "Maths [sic] 'versions'", of the user guide of the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package notes that it quickly becomes highly inefficient to use multiple `\setmathfont` directives midstream within a document -- as happens to be the case in the test document shown above.

Instead, it's advisable to set up "math versions" in the preamble by providing the following instructions

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}[version=XCharter]
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}[version=Garamond]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]
```

and to run `\mathversion{LM} ... \mathversion{Termes} ...` etc instructions in the body of the document to switch between the math versions.

The following test program takes fewer than 8 seconds to compile on my M2-chip MacBook Air that runs MacOS 13.1 "Ventura" and MacTeX2022 with all updates applied. For comparison, it takes 1'33'' to compile the OP's test code (with the multiple midstream `\setmathfont` directives enabled) on my laptop. I think it's fair to call this efficiency gain impressive.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\colorlet{tablerowcolor}{gray!10}
\colorlet{tablesubheadcolor}{Azure4!30}

% set text and math fonts
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}  
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}  

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[version=Termes]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=Pagella]
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}[version=XCharter]
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math}[version=Garamond]
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}[version=Cambria]

% 2 test strings
\newcommand{\textstring}{Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow.}
\newcommand{\mathstring}{$f(u,v) = 
     \iiint [u\nabla^2 v+(\nabla u,\nabla v)]\,\symup{d}^3 V$}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit scope of instructions on next line
\small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
% the table
    \begin{longtblr}[
            caption = {Font examples},
            label   = {tab:doc:Font:Gallery}]
        {
            colspec = {X[1,l] X[2,l]},
            width = 1.0\textwidth,
            row{odd} = {bg=tablerowcolor},
            row{1}   = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily\upshape\bfseries},
            rowhead = 1,
            rowfoot = 0,
        }       
        \hline % Table Header
        Font & Example \\ 
        \hline %        
        %
        \SetCell[c=2]{l,bg=tablesubheadcolor} Text Fonts \\
        Latin Modern Roman   & \rmfamily \textstring \\
        Latin Modern Sans    & \sffamily \textstring \\
        Latin Modern Mono    & \ttfamily \textstring \\
        %
        \SetCell[c=2]{l,bg=tablesubheadcolor} Math Fonts \\
        %
        Latin Modern Math     & \mathversion{LM}        \mathstring \\
        TeX Gyre Termes Math  & \mathversion{Termes}    \mathstring \\
        TeX Gyre Pagella Math & \mathversion{Pagella}   \mathstring \\
        Charter Math          & \mathversion{XCharter}  \mathstring \\
        Garamond Math         & \mathversion{Garamond}  \mathstring \\
        Cambria Math          & \mathversion{Cambria}   \mathstring \\
        % 
        \hline
        %
    \end{longtblr}  
\par\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: I need to read the docs to understand the reason, but it works.

Comment: The package author is from Australia, where they mostly use British spellings (not pronunciation, of course ), so “maths” and not “math” like in American English.